# How can I take value from star images in evaluation system for courses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I want to make evaluation page that allow student to evaluate course:
Here jquery code that are used to change the color of the white images to yellow ones

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        var clickedFlag = false;

        $(".ratingStar").click(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "/Content/images/yellowstar.gif").prevAll("img.ratingStar").attr("src", "/Content/images/yellowstar.gif").attr("value",1);
        });
        $(".ratingStar, #radingDiv").mouseout(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "/Content/images/whitestar.gif");
        });
        $("#ratingDiv").mouseout(function () {
            if (!clickedFlag) {
                $(".ratingStar").attr("src", "/Content/images/whitestar.gif");
            }
        });
        $(".ratingStar").click(function () {
            clickedFlag = true;
            $(".ratingStar").unbind("mouseout mouseover").css("cursor", "default");

            var url = "/EvaluationQuestion/SendRating?r=" + $(this).attr("data-value") + "&s=5&id=@Model&url=@Url";

            });
```

this is html code the display the images of stars

```
  <div id="ratingDiv" class="smallText">
    Poor
    <img src="~/Content/images/whitestar.gif" alt="" class="ratingStar"  data-value="1" />
    <img src="~/Content/images/whitestar.gif" alt="" class="ratingStar" data-value="2" />
    <img src="~/Content/images/whitestar.gif" alt="" class="ratingStar" data-value="3" />
    <img src="~/Content/images/whitestar.gif" alt="" class="ratingStar" data-value="4" />
    <img src="~/Content/images/whitestar.gif" alt="" class="ratingStar" data-value="5" />
        Excellent
    </div>
```

I want to receive the data value of these images in the action of this view

Comment: Please paste in your code instead of providing screenshots so people can test it. Also, can you elaborate on what you want to do?

Comment: You didn't close <script> tag

Comment: Neither <div> tag. Is this a copy-paste 'typo' or you have the same in your code?